# .deb Wps office 2019 only runs as root [kubuntu 21.04]

Tags: permissions, root, deb, wps-office, 21.04

Installed wps office via  .deb package from their website, it only runs as root.

i did chmod 777 with some wps files but it wont help.

i have limited internet access and downloaded the package at a wifi hotspot.

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 3):

`wps` is available from [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/install/wps-2019-snap/ubuntu), you can install it through:

```
sudo snap install wps-2019-snap
```

Comment: I forgot to mention but i have limited internet access and downloaded the package at a wifi hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

you could delete the folder with the name Kingsoft. address: /home/username/.config/Kingsoft

Comment: Why does that help OP ?

Comment: If you install the package used the command 'sudo apt install ./wps-office*.deb ', then you could delete the folder with the name Kingsoft. address: /home/username/.config/Kingsoft 
  .This is a bug. The engineer of WPS told me it would be fixed at the next releases. I don't know why to do these things, but It is effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf ~/.config/Kingsoft
pkill wps
pkill wpp
(not sure which process is for WPS Spreadsheet)
```

This seems to fix my problem.